# Download multiple tweets using tweet IDs at once

Tags: import, social-media

I have a list of tweetIDs and would like to download them all at once. I tried **ServiceConnect["Twitter"]**, but it limits to one tweet per call and is mighty slow (~3s per call/tweet). 
Twitter provides APIs for multiple downloads at once but it limits to downloading 100 at one time. I used the Oauth functions in mathematica but it needs verification after every single call as I am using the **consumer key** instead of **access token**. I am unable to find the right keywords to specify the access tokens. Can someone help me with this? Here is the call that I am making:

```
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json?id=" <> StringRiffle[tweetIDs[[;; 100, 1]], ","];
token = OAuthSigning`OAuthToken[
   "ConsumerKey" -> "CONSUMER_KEY",
   "ConsumerSecret" ->"CONSUMER_SECRET",
   "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
   "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
   "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
URLFetch[url, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token]
```

This works but needs to be verified for access every single time. I also tried this:

```
token2 = OAuthSigning`OAuthToken[
       "OAuthVersion" -> "1.0a",
       "ConsumerKey" -> "CONSUMER_KEY",
       "ConsumerSecret" ->"CONSUMER_SECRET",
       "AccessToken" -> "ACCESS_TOKEN",
       "AccessTokenSecret" -> "ACCESS_SECRET"
       "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
       "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
       "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
```

But I ended up getting a bunch of errors saying:
AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret give values for things that are not valid OAuth 1.0a  properties.

```
In[191]:= $Version

Out[191]= "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"
```

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presently Twitter paclet does not support https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json end point. I have asked the development team to consider adding this request in future versions. Meanwhile one of the developer suggested me a rather simple way of calling this endpoint from mathematica.

```
In[1]:= twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"]

Out[1]= ServiceObject["Twitter", 
 "ID" -> "connection-22ae375a81799332522a0d97ecfc6b2d"]

In[2]:= url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/lookup.json";

In[3]:= ids = (twitter["UserReplies", "Username" -> "donttrythis"])[
    All, "ID"] // Normal;

In[4]:= twitterids = StringRiffle[ids, ","]

Out[4]= "821178765547999232,819195588503867392,818998513979695104,\
818996102795968512,817181239027216386,816816700263796737,\
816766917583118336,815745064185888768,815357650263121920,\
815045109720829952,815043786703147009,815041827854319616,\
815041490384613376,815034501856268289,815031188595220480,\
813474939189673989,813118628262334464,813118334388420608,\
812387175572508672,811394345194557440"

In[5]:= urlstring = URLBuild[{url}, {"id" -> twitterids}];

In[6]:= data = OAuthClient`oauthdata[twitter, urlstring];

In[7]:= res = (<|"ID" -> #["id_str"], "Text" -> #["text"]|>) & /@ 
   ImportString[data, "RawJSON"] // Dataset

Out[7]= Dataset[ <> ]
```

Out[7] looks like below:

[image]